# Simple use of the 'required' attribute but also validate the form (to exclude '@')

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to create a form that ensures the name input field excludes the ‘@‘ symbol but also has the same box appear prompting the user to fill in the field if empty. I assume the box may differ per browser.

To explain my demo further, see this default form:

```
<form id='form-id' action="/" method="post">
  <div class="subscribe-form">
    <div class="form-section">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="name here" id="name-id" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email*" id="email-id" required />
      </div>
          <input id='checkbox-id' type="checkbox" required /> *check here
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="Subscribe">submit</button> <!-- WITH input type submit -->
  </div>
</form>
```

Clicking the submit button will only submit if all fields are completed, but it won’t check if the name field includes an ‘@‘. I can’t edit it to only submit if the field doesn’t include an ‘@‘.

But this demo:

```
<form id='form-id' action="/" method="post">
  <div class="subscribe-form">
    <div class="form-section">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="name here" id="name-id" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email*" id="email-id" required />
      </div>
          <input id='checkbox-id' type="checkbox" required /> *check here
    </div>
    <button onclick="checkName()" type="button" value="Subscribe">submit</button> <!-- changed from input type submit -->
  </div>
<script>
let form = document.getElementById('form-id'),
    ecsName = document.getElementById('name-id'),
    ecsEmail = document.getElementById('email-id'),
    ecsCheckbox =  document.getElementById('checkbox-id');

function checkName() {
  let name = ecsName.value,
      email = ecsEmail.value;

  if(name.includes('@')) {
    alert('includes @');
  } else if (name == '' || email == '') {
    alert('please fill in your details');
  } else if (ecsCheckbox.checked == false) {
    alert ('unckeded');
  } else {
    form.submit();
  }
}
</script>
</form>
```

Includes javascript that ensures all fields are completed, but I don’t like the alert and want the same prompt box to appear as with the former form.

Is there any way of doing this? I’m essentially trying to not tamper with the form and let the default settings do most of the work if possible. Also, another quick question - should `required` be `required='required'`? Thanks for any help here.

Comment: You could use a Validator

Comment: Try adding a pattern to the field: `<input ... pattern="[^@]+" />`.

Comment: to be valid XHTML, yes you need     required="required"

Comment: Thank you for that. What would be the pattern to include an @ rather than exclude? (for the email form) And what's a validator?